# Usage of fiddler api my C# app

Tags: fiddler

I want to use Fiddler API to monitor all the URLs a webpage is requesting and later use their offset to calculate the time taken to load for a particular webpage.

Could anyone help me with how to start?

Comment: I /think/ you're asking "Where can I download FiddlerCore?" See http://fiddler2.com/core/